# Javascript clipboard copy function not working onclick of anchor tag onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I want to `copy` a text into `clipboard` but for some reasons its not working nor it is throwing any `errors`.

Below is my code.

```
function copy(obj)
{
     var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var $tempInput = document.createElement('INPUT');
      $body.appendChild($tempInput);
      $tempInput.setAttribute('value',  '1234')
      $tempInput.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      $body.removeChild($tempInput);
}
```

I want to copy this text on click of anchor tag having href which is causing the issue it seems. Any leads much appreciated.

Comment: The logic works fine for me: `1234` gets copied to the clipboard. What's your problem? What does the error message say? What are you passing into the `obj` argument? I can see that you're not using it at all in your `copy()` method.

Comment: Hi @Terry - I am calling it onclick of  a button in my application. When the function is executed. after i do ctrl+v it does not paste 1234.

Comment: obj has values which i pass as input which i have verified

Comment: You need to reproduce the issue reliably first: because so far, it is working for me just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6wLhp2bf/

Comment: @Terry -  Can you please check onclick of anchor tag ?.

Answer (score 1):

add onclick events

```
onclick="copy(obj)"
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is not using in your function `copy`

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
  location.href='#popup1';
  var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var $tempInput = document.createElement('INPUT');
  $body.appendChild($tempInput);
  $tempInput.setAttribute('value',  '1234')
  $tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $body.removeChild($tempInput);
  alert("Text Copied");
}
```

```html
   
<a class="coup-copybutton" href="#" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</a>
```

Comment: @Deepu - please check using anchor tag.

Comment: @DeepuReghunath - href has a value and not #.

Comment: If we have a value in href then it is appending return false after function by default and because of which copy function is not working.

Comment: @sTg you can give the href value as I given the code. ` location.href='#popup1';`

Answer (score 1):

Your function works perfectly fine, I suspect your issue is with actually calling the function on button click.

Below is the exact same code you have, except I removed the `obj` parameter since it is never used. I also created a button which calls the function when clicked.

```js
function copy()
{
     var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var $tempInput = document.createElement('INPUT');
      $body.appendChild($tempInput);
      $tempInput.setAttribute('value',  '1234')
      $tempInput.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      $body.removeChild($tempInput);
}

document.getElementById("copy_btn").onclick = copy;
```

```html
<button id="copy_btn">Copy</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Paste here..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
export const copyText = (text) => {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('value', text);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.select();
  const result = document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(input);
  return result;
};
```